# Read all code from a .js file and insert into a jade template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Hi all I'm basically trying to make a kind of code comparison thing in a website, so I want to have two snippets of code side by side. Just putting it manually into the Jade template doesn't seem like the best idea, so I was wondering if there was a way I could read in regular JS files and put it into the template.

Basically looking for something like this:

**foo.js**

```
var foo = 'foo';
console.log(foo);
```

**bar.js**

```
var bar = 'bar';
console.log(bar);
```

**template.jade**

```
pre
  code
    // Somehow get all of foo.js code here

pre
  code
    // Somehow get all of bar.js code here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's stopping you from reading each file into a String and putting it on the jade templating context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`include`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/). For example:

```
pre
  code
    include foo.js
```

Of course you'll have to use correct relative path to the script, if the `template.jade` and `foo.js` aren't in the same folder.